# maven-surefire-plugin:2.21 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, testng

While Running the selenium testng project on eclipse I am getting below error:
maven-surefire-plugin:2.21 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved
Its also giving me build failure.
Please help

Comment: Please share the pom.xml file.

Comment: Please add the full error output ...I assume firewall/proxy issue...